# Run Grunt Build before OpenShift Build

Tags: git, node.js, jenkins, gruntjs, openshift

My `grunt build` task creates a `/dist/` which my project depends on. I don't want to include built file in my repository. I would rather use Jenkins to allow for continuous integration builds on my project. This is what I have in my `.openshift/action_hooks/build`, and I'm not sure why it's not running:

```
echo " >>>>>>>>> Building with grunt..."
grunt build
echo " >>>>>>>>> Finished building with grunt..."
```

I know it's not running because I don't see those echo lines in the Jenkins build log or the application log (`rhc tail <app-name>`).

Also, when I ssh into the server and attempt to run `grunt build` manually, it is unable to find the grunt command, so that makes me wonder whether this is possible...

Am I supposed to just include the built files in my repo? If so, when will OpenShift fix this? :)

Let me know if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental issue here is the [openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs](https://github.com/wshearn/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs) and furthermore [npm_global_module_list](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs/versions/shared/configuration/npm_global_module_list) doesn't include grunt/grunt-cli in the global npm modules.

I opened [openshift/origin-server/issues/4069](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/issues/4069) as an RFE to get this in the default cartridge.

In the meantime, I've been working on [engineersamuel/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs](https://github.com/engineersamuel/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs) which includes bower and Grunt support.

My cartridge runs `grunt prod` if a Gruntfile.js is found.  By default grunt is not on the path, this is easily fixed by prefixing the command with the node_modules.

```sh
# If there is a grunt file, run $ grunt prod
if [ -f "${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}"/Gruntfile.js ]; then
    (cd "${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}"; node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt prod)
fi
```

The `./bin/control` also checks for a bower.json file and installs the corresponding packages.

You can quickly and easily test out this custom cartridge with the cartridge reflector with the following command:

`rhc create-app nodejstest "http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=engineersamuel/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs"`

Answer (score 4):

Although this is an old question, I just discovered an answer to this issue that is current.

First, now you can add grunt-cli to you dependencies (`npm install grunt-cli --save`) and Openshift will add those that are commonly installed using the `-g` flag to the path automatically.

From the Openshift site:

> Command line utilities that are usually installed using the -g or --global flag will be automatically be added to the system $PATH, as long as they are included in the dependencies or devDependencies sections of the project’s package.json file.

Inside `.openshift/action_hooks/build` you need to first reset the home directory to be the repo directory, then run `grunt build` then switch the home directory back to the original.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLD_HOME=$HOME
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
export HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR

grunt build

export HOME=$OLD_HOME
```

Now grunt will be able to find your Gruntfile.js and run whatever tasks you need.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use the postinstall phase to execute your grunt task.  First, install grunt-cli in a way you're not supposed to:

```
npm install grunt-cli --save-dev
```

Then, update your package.json to execute `grunt prod` in the postinstall phase:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts" : {
    ...
    "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/grunt prod",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Now when you deploy to OpenShift, and after your dependencies are installed, your grunt task should run.

This solution is not what I would consider *perfect*, but should get the job done so you can get something up and running while you're building a custom cartridge, like @Samuel has done.

Comment: That should be `"postinstall": "export HOME=app-root/runtime/repo; ./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt prod"`

Answer (score -3):

On the Jenkins server, as root, Install npm with Node.js.

On Centos 6, Enable the EPEL repository and run

```
yum install npm
```

Other ways and servers are via: https://serverfault.com/questions/299288/how-do-you-install-node-js-on-centos

Then run:

```
npm install grunt
```

After this, restart Jenkins so it picks up grunt paths properly when running jobs.